# Clearance + Shoulda Matchers not loading on RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda, clearance

I added the following lines to my spec_helper.rb file

```
require 'clearance/testing'
require 'clearance/shoulda_macros'
config.include Clearance::Shoulda::Helpers
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
:239:in `require': no such file to load -- clearance/shoulda_macros (LoadError)
```

Running Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.9 with the latest Shoulda, Clearance, and RSpec-rails gems installed.

Any ideas?